# Generating upper and lowercase letters

Tags: java, char

I'm getting class, interface, or enum errors as well as illegal start of expression. How can I fix this? The code is supposed to generate a password that has upper and lower case letters. It also needs to detect when a letter entered is upper or lower case.

```js
// Returns a random Capital letter as a char
 static private char GenerateCapitalLetter() 
 {
    char returnChar = 'A';

    
    // Write your code here
    // HINT: look at the GenerateNumber() method
    // HINT: think of how to modify GenerateNumber() to generate a Capital letter

 {

    Random random = new Random();
    random.ints(65, 90).limit(10)
      {
            .forEach(a -> System.out.println(Character.toString((char) a)));
            }
     }
 }
}

 
 
 // Generate lowercase letter

static private char GenerateCapitalLetter()
{
 char returnChar = 'a';
 {

    Random random = new Random();
    random.ints(97, 126).limit(10)
      {
            .forEach(a -> System.out.println(Character.toString((char) a)));
            }
     }
 }
}





 // Tests to see if an input char is a Capital letter in code below

 
 // Tests to see if an input char is a lowercase letter     
char input=' ';
{
    if (Character.isLowerCase(input) || Character.isUpperCase(input))
     {
        if (Character.isLowerCase(input))
            System.out.println("lower");
        } else {
            System.out.println("upper");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's with all the inner braces?

Comment: You're missing `;` after the `random` statements; `GenerateCapitalLetter` is declared twice, but suspect that's a copy/paste issue; No idea what the `foreach` is trying to do...

Comment: Okay thank you! My teacher gave us parts of the code to use (that's what the foreach is) but I'm suspecting some of it is incorrect.

Comment: I "think" it should be more like ... `random.ints(65, 90).limit(10).forEach(a -> System.out.println((char) a)));`